# less self references how to?

Tags: css, compilation, less

having body which has dynamically generated classes I want to reference the case when body has cms-index-index

so the pseudo

```
body {
   if has body class cms-index-index
   .navigation{
     do not add background color
   }  
}


<body class="some-class .cms-index-index">
  <nav class="navigation"></nav>
</body>
```

how do I do this with less?

Comment: `body.cms-index-index`?

Comment: Then what's your question?

Comment: so navigation has a specific background color inside body but if `body.cms-index-index`  is present than navigation should be transparent. with sass I can reference parent with `&`

Comment: LESS has the same syntax.  See the documentation.

Comment: Are you looking to statically generate the classes with required properties or dynamically decide whether background color should be set or not?